# jquery auto complete sugessions does not display

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I need when I start type on text box automatically get sugessions from database.then when I  select a sugession automatically should fill other text fields which are relate to the selected choice.

here is my code,

**view**

```
<body>
<link rel="stylesheet"      href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.6/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://static.jquery.com/ui/css/demo-docs-theme/ui.theme.css" type="text/   css" media="all" />  
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.6/jquery-ui.min.js"     type="text/javascript"></script>  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-         ui.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var ac_config = {
        source: "<?php echo site_url('birds/get_birds'); ?>",
        select:function(event, ui){
            $("#city").val(ui.item.value);
            $("#location").val(ui.item.location);
            $("#label").val(ui.item.label);
        },
        minLength:2
    };
    $("#birds").autocomplete(ac_config);
})
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var ac_config = {
    source: "<?php echo site_url('birds/get_payee_data'); ?>",
    select:function(event, ui){
        $("#payeename").val(ui.item.name2);
        $("#payee_address").val(ui.item.address2);
    },
    minLength:2
    };
    $("#test").autocomplete(ac_config);
})
</script>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
      $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy" });
    });
</script>


<form action="#" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="birds" />
    <p>city: <input type="text" id="city"/></p>
    <p>location: <input type="text" id="location"/></p>
    <p>label: <input type="text" id="label"/></p>
    <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"/></p>
    <input type="text" id="test" />
    <p>name: <input type="text" id="payeename"/></p>
    <p>address: <input type="text" id="payee_address"/></p>
</form>
```

**controller**

```
class Birds extends CI_Controller{
function index(){
$this->load->view('birds_view');
}

function get_birds(){
  $this->load->model('birds_model');
 if (isset($_GET['term'])){
  $q = strtolower($_GET['term']);
  $this->birds_model->get_bird($q);
 }
 }

 public function get_payee_data(){
    $this->load->model('birds_model');
    if (isset($_GET['term'])){
      $ss = strtolower($_GET['term']);
      $this->birds_model->load_payee_data($ss);
    }
  }
}
```

**model**

```
function get_bird($q){
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->like('bird', $q);
$query = $this->db->get('birds');
if($query->num_rows > 0){
  foreach ($query->result_array() as $row){
    $new_row['label']=htmlentities(stripslashes($row['bird']));
    $new_row['value']=htmlentities(stripslashes($row['aka']));
    $new_row['city']=htmlentities(stripslashes($row['city']));
    $new_row['location']=htmlentities(stripslashes($row['location']));
    $row_set[] = $new_row; //build an array
   }
   echo json_encode($row_set); //format the array into json data
  }
 }

 function load_payee_data($ss){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->like('name', $ss);
    $query = $this->db->get('payee_details');
    //$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM payee_details WHERE name LIKE '%q%' ");
    if($query->num_rows > 0){
      foreach ($query->result_array() as $row){
    $new_row['name2']=htmlentities(stripslashes($row['name']));
    $new_row['address2']=htmlentities(stripslashes($row['address']));
    $row_set2[] = $new_row; //build an array
      }
      echo json_encode($row_set2); //format the array into json data
    }
  }
```

under the gihan shows sugessions

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are using/including two separate versions of jquery, that'll be the root cause of the issue.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
```